# Zabbix agent not using the .my.cnf

Tags: mysql, zabbix-agent, my.cnf

I have a server with a zabbix agent installed, this is working fine.

I want to monitor a database on the server, I have followed the documentation of `MySQL by Zabbix agent`.

I have an error inside the log

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Here is a longer part of the logs:

```
 15110:20220919:154820.657 In zbx_waitpid()
 15110:20220919:154820.657 zbx_waitpid() exited, status:0
 15110:20220919:154820.658 End of zbx_waitpid():15142
 15110:20220919:154820.658 Run remote command [ mysqladmin -h"127.0.0.1" -P"3306" ping] Result [0] []...
 15110:20220919:154820.658 Sending back []
 15110:20220919:154820.658 listener #2 [waiting for connection]
 15110:20220919:154820.719 listener #2 [processing request]
 15110:20220919:154820.719 Requested [system.cpu.util[,iowait]]
 15110:20220919:154820.719 Sending back [0.071416]
 15110:20220919:154820.719 listener #2 [waiting for connection]
 15111:20220919:154821.077 listener #3 [processing request]
 15111:20220919:154821.077 Requested [mysql.ping["127.0.0.1","3306"]]
 15111:20220919:154821.077 In zbx_popen() command:' mysqladmin -h"127.0.0.1" -P"3306" ping'
 15111:20220919:154821.078 End of zbx_popen():8
 15143:20220919:154821.078 zbx_popen(): executing script
mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
 15111:20220919:154821.089 In zbx_waitpid()
 15111:20220919:154821.089 zbx_waitpid() exited, status:0
 15111:20220919:154821.089 End of zbx_waitpid():15143
 15111:20220919:154821.089 Run remote command [ mysqladmin -h"127.0.0.1" -P"3306" ping] Result [0] []...
 15111:20220919:154821.089 Sending back []
 15111:20220919:154821.090 listener #3 [waiting for connection]
 15112:20220919:154821.114 In send_buffer() host:'<ip>' port:10051 values:0/100
 15112:20220919:154821.114 End of send_buffer():SUCCEED
 15112:20220919:154821.114 active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]
 15108:20220919:154821.116 collector [processing data]
 15108:20220919:154821.116 In update_cpustats()
 15108:20220919:154821.116 End of update_cpustats()
 15108:20220919:154821.116 collector [idle 1 sec]
 15109:20220919:154821.543 listener #1 [processing request]
```

But my `.my.cnf` that is in `/var/run/zabbix/` look like that:

```
[client]
user='zbx_monitor'
password='<password>'
```

The home directory of the `zabbix` user is `/var/run/zabbix/` so it should work.

I have done it on other servers and it worked fine. But on this one the `.my.cnf` is not working and I can't find why.

The only things different between the server:

- Home directory
- Server date, so not the same linux version

Do you have any idea what could cause this problem ?

## Edit:

```
namei -l /var/run/zabbix/.my.cnf

f: /var/run/zabbix/.my.cnf
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   var
lrwxrwxrwx root   root   run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x root   root     /
drwxr-xr-x root   root     run
drwxr-xr-x zabbix zabbix zabbix
-rw-r----- zabbix zabbix .my.cnf
```

If I try to run the command with the user `zabbix` it works:

```
sudo -u zabbix mysqladmin -h"127.0.0.1" -P"3306" ping
mysqld is alive
```

So the error is happening only when it's the zabbix agent that run the command.

Here is the home directory of my zabbix user

```
getent passwd zabbix
zabbix:x:109:115::/var/run/zabbix/:/bin/false
```

Comment: What are the ownership and the permissions of .my.cnf?

Comment: Here is the permissions of `.my.cnf`: `-rwxrwxrwx  1 zabbix zabbix  48 sept. 14 10:58 .my.cnf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even so the home directory of my Zabbix user is `/var/run/zabbix`, it seem that it's not the directory that is used as a home by zabbix commands.

I changed `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/template_db_mysql.conf` like that, I added the `HOME=/var/run/zabbix` before each command:

```
UserParameter=mysql.ping[*],HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysqladmin -h"$1" -P"$2" ping
UserParameter=mysql.get_status_variables[*], HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysql -h"$1" -P"$2" -sNX -e "show global status"
UserParameter=mysql.version[*], HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysqladmin -s -h"$1" -P"$2" version
UserParameter=mysql.db.discovery[*], HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysql -h"$1" -P"$2" -sN -e "show databases"
UserParameter=mysql.dbsize[*], HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysql -h"$1" -P"$2" -sN -e "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH),0) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='$3'"
UserParameter=mysql.replication.discovery[*], HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysql -h"$1" -P"$2" -sNX -e "show slave status"
UserParameter=mysql.slave_status[*], HOME=/var/run/zabbix mysql -h"$1" -P"$2" -sNX -e "show slave status"
```

Comment: Thanks, only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The permissions of your `.my.cnf` are too wide open.

```
$ ls -l .my.cnf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 44 Sep 14 15:40 .my.cnf
$ mysqladmin ping
mysqladmin: [Warning] World-writable config file '/home/user/.my.cnf' is ignored.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
```

Set the proper permissions.

```
chmod 640 /var/run/zabbix/.my.cnf
```

Comment: I ran the chmod, but I still have the same error. Here is the permissions `-rw-r-----  1 zabbix zabbix  48 sept. 14 10:58 .my.cnf`. How do you get this error ? When I cd myself inside the `/var/run/zabbix`and do the same command I get `'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. I can't log in as `zabbix` since the shell is `/bin/false`.

Comment: Please edit the output of `namei -l /var/run/zabbix/.my.cnf` into your question.

Comment: Ok, I just added the infos you asked

Comment: Are you sure about the location of the zabbix home directory? On my systems (installed via official packages) the home directory is in `/var/lib/zabbix/`. Please edit the output of `grep zabbix /etc/passwd` into your question. `/var/run` is usually linked to `/run`, which is usually a non permanent directory that is reset at reboot.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is. On other servers yes the home directory was `/var/lib/zabbix`. Maybe its because this server is older, and zabbix agent was installed some years ago. Should I change the zabbix home directory ? Inside `/var/run/zabbix/` there is a folder `.rpmdb`and a file `zabbix_agentd.pid`

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the single quotes around your values,

```
[client] 
user='zbx_monitor' 
password='<password>'
```

Let us know how it works out.

Comment: I have removed the single quotes from the `.my.cnf` and I still have the same error

Comment: @GregoryBoutte Please post a snippet of your error log that includes this failure being recorded - plus 10 lines before and 10 lines after the event.

Comment: I have added some lines, but I have found the solution, which I have posted.